# How to save Password with encryption algorithms in Sql Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, password-encryption

I'm making a program in C# which includes userdata like Username and Passowrd. I have created a Database in SQL Server 2008 and now I want to encrypt Passowrd in my Database because I wouldn't like to see their passwords.

I hope you will help me about this.

- DB name: `db_Biblioteka`
- Table: `tbl_Users`
- Columns: `ID`, `Name`, `Username`, `Password`

Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest searching the internet, making an attempt, and THEN come back if you get stuck.

Comment: Hint: you don't want to 'encrypt' your passwords, you want to hash them. These are *not* the same thing. Now you probably have some googling to do...

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945820/hash-encrypting-password-when-inserting-into-database?rq=1 - that gives a nice answer. But also read a little about hashing so you understand exactly what's going on; there's quite a lot of good information about.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to [Encrypt a Column of Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx), so follow the link.

> But for more security on sniffing you need to encode your password on passing them to SQL Server.

So you can use many functions in your code to do that; And the easiest way is:

```
public static string GetHashText(string txt)
{
    byte[] tmpSource = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(txt);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(tmpSource);
}

public static string DecodeText(string txt)
{
    byte[] tmpData = Convert.FromBase64String(txt);
    string tmp = new UTF8Encoding().GetString(tmpData);
    return tmp;
}
```

> But the better way is `Hashing` (@simon). And you can use this [Hash Code](http://www.obviex.com/Samples/Hash.aspx)

Comment: Encryption is not the recommended way to handle storing passwords. Hashing is.

Comment: The problem with that example code it that it uses a random salt, which is going to make checking a logon a bit difficult.

Comment: @simonatrcl I just add that link for an example or a start point for OP, I think we should help OP to find his or her way ;).

Comment: Indeed. Have a look at my comment to the question. Anything crypto needs a bit of understanding; a half answer is usually worse than none at all.