# C# Login system, need help hashing password before inserting them to the database

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, authentication, md5

Hi I'm woking on a C# project for school, I'm creating a basic login/register system in C# and use MySQL for my database. My Question is how do I hash the passwords with md5 and insert the hashed password in to the database?

I don't have any example code since i haven't yet started this project. The due is not until after spring break.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to help you if you haven't attempted anything.

Comment: Answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945820/hash-encrypting-password-when-inserting-into-database).

Comment: you can google "MD5CryptoServiceProvider"

Comment: I would not use MD5 [read this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hash a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181198/how-to-hash-a-password)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple sample of an extension method...
Usage... string.Sha256() like "password".Sha256()

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension methods for hashing strings
    /// </summary>
    public static class HashExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a SHA256 hash of the specified input.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input">The input.</param>
        /// <returns>A hash</returns>
        public static string Sha256(this string input)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                using (var sha = SHA256.Create())
                {
                    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
                    var hash = sha.ComputeHash(bytes);

                    return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```